# How do I make an Excel VBA Function that works when I reopen the document?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, excel-2010

OK, I've just written a very simple VBA script that goes off and grabs the file size of a file found at a specified location (***edit*** update code from [dscarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637931/dscarr)):

```
Public Function FileSize(path As String) As Variant 
    On Error GoTo Err_FileSize:
    Dim retVal As Variant 
    Dim filesys As Object 
    Dim file As Object 
    retVal = "" 
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set file = filesys.GetFile(path) 
    retVal = file.Size 

    Exit_FileSize: On Error Resume Next 
    FileSize = retVal 
    Exit Function 

    Err_FileSize: retVal = "Error: " & Err.Description 
    Resume Exit_FileSize 
End Function
```

If I import this into a new workbook, save the document as a "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook" alongside an empty file called `readme.txt` and then put "./readme.txt" in A1 and "=FileSize(A1)" in A2, A2 evaluates properly to the file size of `readme.txt`, 0 bytes. Great. If I then save the document, close and reopen it, I'm warned that macros are disabled. If I enable them, the content of A2 has changed to `#VALUE!` and nothing I do will make the function work again. Has anyone seen this before, can anyone point out the mistake that I'm making here?

***edit***: the issue seems to be caused by me using relative paths. I can't explain why it works for a new workbook, but not once saved and reopened, but using absolute paths solves the problem, which as dscarr identified, was a "File Not Found" issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I duplicated your code in an Excel 2007 Macro Enabled workbook and found that it worked just fine with the following caveats

1. It does not automatically update the value (e.g. run the FileSize function) when you open the workbook. This can be compensated for by adding some code to the Worrkbook_Open event handler that calculates the workbook.
2. I get the #VALUE error when it cannot find the file that is specified. Indeed, when the file is missing or incorrectly named the line "Set file = filesys.GetFile(path)" throws the error number 53 "File Not Found". In this case the return value is never set because the line of code that sets it is never called. You could try setting a default value of "File Not Found" before actually attempting to retrieve the file size.

Comment: ahh progress! excellent work my friend! The problem seems to be the resolution of relative paths. If I use a full path, it works perfectly (without re-evaluation on open, as you point out). How do I get the error code back? I tried to "watch" filesys object, but it just goes out of scope when the GetFile fails.

Comment: Also, It appears that the cell is not re-calculating because the cells that it is dependent onhave not changed. To force Excel to recalculate everyting, reguardless of whether it has changed or not, add the statement "Application.CalculateFull" to the Workbook_Open event.

Comment: The error number can be retrieved using the Err object. Example: Err.Number

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting your function a bit. <hmmmm obviously you can't put line feeds in these comment fields . . .

Comment: is there any way I can get around the relative path issue? are you able to reproduce that behaviour, or am I going insane?

Comment: Public Function FileSize(path As String) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Err_FileSize
    
    Dim retVal As Variant
    Dim filesys As Object
    Dim file As Object
    
    retVal = ""
    
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set file = filesys.GetFile(path)
    
    retVal = file.Size
    
Exit_FileSize:
    On Error Resume Next
    FileSize = retVal
    Exit Function
    
Err_FileSize:
    retVal = "Error: " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_FileSize
    
End Function

Comment: Not sure about the relative path where the FileSystem Object is concerned. You can get the path of the Workbook with this statement "strSomeStringVariable = ThisWorkbook.Path"

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010, Go File->Options->Trust Center->Macro Settings and make sure the Enable option button has been selected.

Comment: It's not the enabling that causes me upset, it's the fact that the function no longer works.

Comment: @ninesided, I agree with dscarr's Workbook_Open idea.